# Как найти объект значение которого равно 0 по тегу?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Всем привет.
Делаю игру на unity и есть уровень с боссом, после убийства которого должна высвечиваться надпись о выигрыше.
Так вот вопрос как найти этот объект, чтобы значение его было равно 0, после убийства?
Код прилагается. В программировании пока что чайник:)

```
[Header("Enemies")]
public GameObject enemyTypes;
public Transform[] enemySpawners;

[HideInInspector] public List<GameObject> enemies;

public GameObject success;
public GameObject welcome;


public void Start() 
{
    welcome.SetActive(true);
    StartCoroutine(CheckEnemies());
}

IEnumerator CheckEnemies() 
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    welcome.SetActive(false);
        foreach(Transform spawner in enemySpawners)
        {
                GameObject enemyType = enemyTypes;
                GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyType, spawner.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                enemy.transform.parent = transform;
                enemies.Add(enemy);
        }
    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    if(GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy") == null) 
    {
        Success();
    }
}

public void Success() 
{
    success.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: Значение надписи? или значение босса? и почему вообще 0? после победы?

Comment: Значение босса у него тег enemy
Ну я думаю, что 0 это его отсутствие на сцене, может и ошибаюсь
Смысл в том, что если он убит, т.е он отсутствует, то только тогда появляется надпись о выигрыше

Comment: тег никак не влияет на присутствие/отсутствие объекта на сцене. напиши сценарий для босса, в котором будет его удаление, показ панели о победе и что еще ты хочешь сделать(какие нибудь эффекты запустить и т.д.)

Comment: Походу поняяял)
Нужно добавить в скрипт босса, что если hp<0, то будет высвечиваться надпись?

Comment: выдели в этом скрипте какой-нибудь метод "Death" в котором уже будешь делать Destroy(босса) и показывать панель

Comment: Ну у меня есть скрипт где health <= 0, то вызывается эффект и дестрой

Comment: Понимаю, что ответ уже получили, но могу добавить, что если у вас много разных врагов, то вы можете создать функцию Death() в классе Enemy, а для босса создать отдельный класс - так как он сильно отличается от обычного врага. В методе Death в классе Enemy вы можете прописать стандартные действия на убийство стандартного врага - обычно это выдача монет (опыта, дропа...), возможно увеличение еще какой-то переменной для подсчета убитых врагов и уничтожения врага в конце метода. А в классе Boss, унаследованном от Enemy переопределяете метод Death и пишите функциональность на смерть босса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давай на псевдокоде напишу. Это методы класса `BossCherbos`, у которого есть здоровье и ссылка на табличку победы.

```
public void ApplyDamage(int damage)
{
    if(Health > damage)
       Health -= damage;
    else Death();
}

public void Death()
{
    _winPanel.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: Почему то просто text не высвечивается, но думаю, что разберусь
Спасибо большое за ответ, в правильное русло направили меня